# "Conflicting assets with the same target path" error message from Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm making a project for school, and decided on doing a theater-administration website. A part of the assignment says to include a small WPF that can use your own API.

However, when I added an API project to the solution it started giving me this error, and I don't understand what it means. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm not allowed to embed images yet, so the screenshot will be in the link below.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXG3q.png)

Comment: It's hard to find the real cause with just the error message.